# Creating an interactive menu in python console

Tags: python, menu, module, refresh

so im trying to make a program in python that shows a menu when the program is launched.  I want something with a few options that updates when you use the up and down arrow keys to select an option with the enter key that will launch the module for the option selected.

-->Option 1<--

---Option 2---

---Option 3---

---Exit---

Pressing the down arrow key would change to next option.

---Option 1---

-->Option 2<--

---Option 3---

---Exit---

And so on like this, anyone got any ideas?  I am a bit rusty with terminology so if i could get some answers in lamens terms that would be great.

Comment: this would be pretty easy to do with tkinter.

Comment: What have you tried so far? This isn't exactly a specific programming _problem_ as described in [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  It also states that; "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow."

Comment: The computer I am on now doesnt have the code I have so far but the basic idea behind it is use a list to have all the options for the menu.  When the program starts it will print ---list_item[0]--- and then the next list item on the next line with the selected list item having a --><-- instead of the 3 dashes on each end.  I am stuck on the part where I use the arrow keys to move the selection as well as having the output refresh instead of printing it out again every time I change selection.  A few years when I was using python I was mainly using pi game so I dont know much about the console

Comment: You could maybe look into [`curses`](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/curses.html) or [`Urwid`](http://lwn.net/Articles/172998/) but I'm fairly sure python has no control over an actual console/terminal window that pipes its in/outputs.

Comment: If you are interested in a `tkinter` implementation please comment and I'd be happy to post an answer.  Otherwise I'm going to assume a user interface isn't what you were looking for.